# How to split number like money format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For example:

```
12000 = 12 000
5000 = 5 000
1000000 = 1 000 000
20000000 = 20 000 000
```

Without javascript :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `number_with_delimiter(12000, :delimiter => ' ')`

Answer (score 4):

Hiya is this what you are looking for:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html

like - number_to_currency(1234567890.506, :locale => :fr)   # => 1 234 567 890,51 €

hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Before question requirements were changed:

```
number = 12000
number_to_currency(number, :precision => 0, :unit => "", :delimiter =>  number.to_s.length > 4 ? " " : "") # 12 000

number = 5000
number_to_currency(number, :precision => 0, :unit => "", :delimiter =>  number.to_s.length > 4 ? " " : "") # 5000

number = 1000000
number_to_currency(number, :precision => 0, :unit => "", :delimiter =>  number.to_s.length > 4 ? " " : "") # 1 000 000

number = 20000000
number_to_currency(number, :precision => 0, :unit => "", :delimiter =>  number.to_s.length > 4 ? " " : "") # 20 000 000
```

After question requirements have been changed:

```
number_to_currency(number, :precision => 0, :unit => "", :delimiter =>  " ")
```

Answer (score 2):

In pure Ruby:

```
"20000000".reverse.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join).join(' ').reverse
```

So by all means use a helper method.